# select query with variable(which contains space)

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select

I am running following query to display records.

```
$weavername = $_GET["weavername"];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT co.contId, 
                        co.contDate, 
                        co.quality, 
                        co.width,
                        co.weight,
                        co.quantity,
                        co.rate,
                        co.deliveryDate,
                        co.paymentTerms,
                        pa.partyName, 
                        we.weaverName 
                FROM contract co 
                INNER JOIN party pa ON (co.partyId = pa.partyId)
                INNER JOIN weaver we ON (co.weaverId = we.weaverId) 
WHERE we.weavername = '".$weavername."' ORDER BY co.contId");
echo mysql_error();
```

Now my `$weavername` variable contains spaces e.g. `Tulasi Cotton Mills`. So when I run the query I doesn't display any records because it only takes `Tulasi` as a comparison.

How do I get to match `Tulasi Cotton Mills` in my query?

I also tried LIKE '$weavername%' but it also displays records with weavername `Tulasi Fabrics`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `WHERE we.weavername LIKE '".$weavername."'`...

Comment: I tried that David..still same result...

Comment: Please, stop whatever you're doing and **immediately** read up on [SQL injection protection](http://bobby-tables.com/) and [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). What you're doing here is extremely dangerous. If this code is on the public internet, your entire site could be completely destroyed, or worse.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is in MyISAM, you could setup a full text index, then do a match on "Tulasi Cotton Mills".  Chances are, you will get results that don't match exactly.